# How to Get Half Circle Scrolling Effect in Javascript

Tags: gsap, custom-scrolling

I've been working on cloning [suno.ai](https://www.suno.ai/) for learning purposes, and I'm facing two challenges. Firstly, I've successfully implemented a play song on scroll functionality using GSAP scroll trigger, but I'm struggling to figure out how to rotate these elements in a half circle as seen on [suno.ai](https://www.suno.ai/).

You can check my live site [here](https://remarkable-belekoy-eddc48.netlify.app/).

If anyone has insights or guidance on achieving both the play song on scroll and the rotating elements in a half circle effect, I would greatly appreciate your help!

Thank you.

I've tried placing elements around a circle and rotating a div on scroll, but it won't work as expected.

Comment: You are required to post a [mcve] here within your question and not a link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had seen one tutorial of this, I don't remember the channel but here is what I created.
Check this out

```js
const songsContainer = document.querySelector('#songs')
const songs = songsContainer.querySelectorAll('span')
const skip = songsContainer.querySelectorAll('span.skip').length
const perSongRotationPercentage = 100 / (songs.length - skip)

const totalRotation = 180

const onScroll = () => {
    const maxScrollY = songsContainer.clientHeight - window.innerHeight
    const scrollPercentage = window.scrollY / maxScrollY * 100

    for (let i = 0; i < songs.length; i++) {
        const rotationPercentage = i * perSongRotationPercentage
        const rotation = rotationPercentage / 100 * totalRotation;
        const scrollRotation = scrollPercentage / 100 * totalRotation;
        const skipRotation = skip * perSongRotationPercentage / 100 * totalRotation;

        songs[i].style.transform = `rotate(${rotation - scrollRotation - skipRotation}deg)`
        songs[i].classList.remove('active');
    }

    const nSongs = songs.length - skip;
    const activeSongIndex = skip + Math.round(scrollPercentage / 100 * nSongs)
    songs[activeSongIndex]?.classList.add('active');
}

addEventListener("scroll", onScroll)
onScroll()

for (let i = skip; i < songs.length; i++) {
    songs[i].addEventListener('click', () => {
        const percentage = perSongRotationPercentage * (i - skip);
        window.scrollTo({ top: (percentage / 100) * (songsContainer.clientHeight - window.innerHeight), behavior: 'smooth' })
    })
}
```

```css
html,
body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    font-family: 'Inter', sans-serif;
    overscroll-behavior: none;
    overflow-x: clip;
    background: #050510;
    color: white;
}

html::-webkit-scrollbar {
    display: none;
}

#songs {
    height: 600vh;
    position: relative;
}

.follow-screen {
    height: 100vh;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    margin-left: -30vw;
}

#songs span {
    position: absolute;
    transform-origin: left;
    padding-left: 40vw;
    white-space: nowrap;
    user-select: none;
    transition: transform 200ms ease-out , opacity 300ms ease-in-out;
    font-size: 4.5vw;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#songs span.active {
    --flag-scale: .7;
}

#songs span:not(.active):not(.skip) {
    opacity: 0.5;
}

#songs span.skip {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .2;
}

#songs span::before {
    content: var(--flag);
    font-family: 'Noto Color Emoji';
    position: absolute;
    left: 35vw;
    scale: var(--flag-scale, 0);
    transition: scale 200ms ease-in-out;
}

#songs span:not(.skip):not(.active):hover {
    opacity: .7;
    cursor: pointer;
}

/* Additional content: could be anything, this is just to show how the songs would fade out of the screen */
.next-trip {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100%;
    margin-top: -50vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;

    & img {
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        object-fit: cover;
        position: absolute;
        --mask-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 1) 100%);
        mask-image: var(--mask-image);
        -webkit-mask-image: var(--mask-image);
    }

    & span {
        z-index: 1;
        text-shadow: 0px 0px 4px white;
        user-select: none;
        text-align: center;
    }

    & .small-text {
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    & .big-text {
        font-size: 6em;
    }
}
```

```html
<head>
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Inter:wght@700&family=Noto+Color+Emoji&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="songs">
        <div class="follow-screen">
            <span class="skip">Celtic magic in Wales</span>
            <span class="skip">Cuisine captivates France's essence</span>
            <span class="skip">Siesta echoes through Spain</span>
            <span class="skip">Chocolate indulgence, Belgium's pride</span>
            <span class="skip">Home sweet home</span>
            <span class="skip">Luxe in Luxembourg's lap</span>
            <span class="skip">Oktoberfest joy, Germany's celebration</span>
            <span class="skip">Fjords define Norway's beauty</span>
            <span class="skip">Nordic serenity, Sweden's calm</span>
            <span class="skip">Alpine vistas grace Switzerland</span>
            <span class="skip">Vienna waltz, Austria's melody</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Hygge embraces Denmark's streets</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Andes echo in Chile</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Samba heartbeats, Brazil's rhythm</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Tango thrives in Argentina</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Andean peaks define Bolivia</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Fado serenades Portugal</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">London's charm enchants England</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Highlands whisper Scotland's tales</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Celtic magic in Wales</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Cuisine captivates France's essence</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Siesta echoes through Spain</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Chocolate indulgence, Belgium's pride</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Home sweet home</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Luxe in Luxembourg's lap</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Bratwurst, beer, Oktoberfest cheer</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Fjords define Norway's beauty</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Nordic serenity, Sweden's calm</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Alpine vistas grace Switzerland</span>
            <span style="--flag: ''">Vienna waltz, Austria's melody</span>  
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="next-trip">
        <span class="small-text">Next trip</span>
        <span class="big-text">Costa Rica</span>
    </div>

   
</body>
```